# Piping a multipart file upload to a S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, pipe, multipart, aws-sdk-js

I would like to pipe a file upload that I receive from a multipart request to a S3 bucket using `express` and `aws-sdk`.

I use the `upload` function, it can use a readable stream for the `Body` parameter.

```js
await s3Client
  .upload({
    Bucket: 'some_bucket',
    Key: `records/recordXYZ`,
    Body: req,
    ContentType: 'audio/x-wav,
  })
  .promise();
```

`req` is from express. The request is correctly parsed, the issue is that in the created file in S3 I retrieve some fields from the multipart request that I don't want into. The file is unreadable.

What is inside the file in S3 :

```
--JP2kMlzhqj2uAUdy4al132WFLRexf1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="aFile"; filename="test.wav"
Content-Type: audio/wav
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

RIFF|  WAVEfmt ...
```

Want I need is only :

```
RIFF|  WAVEfmt ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with `multer-s3` : https://github.com/badunk/multer-s3